# routing form submission to different controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, simple-form

problem: I have a form but the submit button doesn't do anything.

i instantiate the class the form is for in the employee_controller controller.

```
  def employee
    @body_class = "employee membership"
    @employee_contact_form = CorporateContactForm.new
  end
```

I create the form in the page the above controller action serves

```
  = simple_form_for [@employee_contact_form] do |f|
    = f.input :firstname
    = f.button :submit
```

In my routes I set the resources for the contact forms

```
  resources :corporate_contact_forms
```

I then have a controller that serves the form

```
class CorporateContactFormsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    raise
  end
```

I am aware there is no code in the corporatecontactcontroller, but the submit button should at least fire to an error. It doesn't do anything.

This feels like such a simple problem, and surely it is. 
What am I missing?

update

html output

```
<form>
              <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/corporate_contact_forms" class="simple_form new_corporate_contact_form" id="new_corporate_contact_form" method="post"><div style="display:none"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="7iMwWQOuyzV3jJt4jTtr9MGvI129hPaG+m+Pe2D3YyM=" /></div>        <div class="input string optional corporate_contact_form_firstname"><label class="string optional" for="corporate_contact_form_firstname">Firstname</label><input class="string optional" id="corporate_contact_form_firstname" maxlength="255" name="corporate_contact_form[firstname]" size="255" type="text" /></div>
                      <input class="button" name="commit" type="submit" value="Create Corporate contact form" />
              </form>
            </form>
```

Comment: whats the html of the form output look like?

Comment: Try change `= f.button :submit` to `= f.submit`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documetation (http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for), you can do something like this to force the form to go to `CorporateContactFormsController#create`

```
<%= simple_form_for @employee_contact_form, url: corporate_contact_forms_path, method: :post do |f| %>
    # awesome code...
<% end %>
```

Also I'm not sure if the `f.button :submit` has something to do, the default for submitting is `f.submit`

Comment: You don't always need to specify url option. If you check the action part in html generated by form you'll see that url is already correct so this won't solve the issue